# listing emails from gmail with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, jakarta-mail

---

## I want to retrieve all my emails from Gmail with spring

I found that spring integration provide a class named ImapMailReceiver
but this  doesn't work
the documentation says that I have to add java mail api implementation SO  I added this dependency angus-mail

```
try {
    ImapMailReceiver imapMailReceiver = new ImapMailReceiver(s);
    imapMailReceiver.receive();
 } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

`s="imap://username@gmail.com:pass@imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX"` 
Is there anyone who has a suggestion for how to proceed ?

ERROR:

```
Factory method 'mailReceiver' threw exception with message: jakarta.mail.MessagingException: Connection dropped by server?
```

Comment: Have you checked that IMAP is enabled? https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-check-that-imap-is-turned-on%2Cstep-change-smtp-other-settings-in-your-email-client I also think you need to use `imaps://` for SSL but I do not know the ImapMailReceiver client

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Integration Mail module is fully based on Java Mail API. How to configure a Java Mail client is out of Spring Integration scope. So, make yourself familiar with GMail requirements for Java Mail API first. The go through `ImapMailReceiver` Javadocs to see if you need to provide anything else, not just an URL:

https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/tree/master/java

https://www.tzhwang.com/2022/01/28/using-javamail-to-search-gmail-with-imap/